# Have any Marvel heroes been drawn differently to match their MCU equivalents?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Have any of the **Marvel comic artists** talked about the influence the actors playing the characters they draw has had on their depiction of these characters?

For example, has Robert Downey-Junior influenced Tony Stark, or Dave Batista Drax, etc.?

Comment: Note that none of the answers of the marked duplicate answer this question. In fact the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: My question is specifically have artists spoken about this, not in peoples opinion do characters look the same now, or have they changed?

Comment: @OrangeDog Answers being wrong doesn't play into whether a dupe closure should happen or not.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot true, but it's still also a different question. The current duplicate is borderline opinion-based as well (hence the low-quality answers). IMO the best outcome is to get a good answer here, and make the old question a duplicate of this.

Comment: @OrangeDog If you think the questions are duplicates, reopening serves nothing and is against SE practices. You should instead try and get a better answer on the old question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't think they're duplicates, that's the point.

Comment: @OrangeDog _"IMO the best outcome is to get a good answer here, and make the old question a duplicate of this."_ Evidently you do.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot questions get closed as duplicates when they aren't duplicates all the time (see this question). If the linked target actually has an answer that answers the question then this is a good outcome, because people who find the question then get an answer to it.